# Как сделать нагрузочное тестирование SMTP-сервиса?

Tags: тестирование, smtp, нагрузочное-тестирование

Я хочу сделать нагрузочное тестирование SMTP-сервиса.
Приблизительный объем писем - **40 000** в час.

Как можно правильно провести нагрузочное тестирование?
Я вижу только один путь -  сделать клиент-консольку, которая в цикле в час вышлет **40к** писем. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: Есть вариант тестировать в 10 потоков, т.к. тестирование по-сети в один поток даже не нагружает сетку. Оптимальное число потоков - подобрать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Apache.JMeter: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler